# Limitation on interactive 3D graphics in the cloud

Tags: graphics3d, cloud-deploy

I'm using a trial version of Mathematica 11.

I am faced with the problem that I was not able to rotate or resize my 3D plot in the cloud, when the number of objects reached magic 33.

here is a code

```
CloudDeploy[

 surr = {{0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {8.377`, 0.`, 0.`}, {6.285`, 
    2.095`, -4.187`}, {6.285`, 2.095`, 4.19`}, {0.`, 2.095`, 
    2.095`}, {8.377`, 2.095`, 2.095`}, {6.285`, 
    0.`, -2.0925`}, {6.285`, 0.`, 
    6.285`}, {4.19`, -2.0925`, 2.095`}, {4.19`, 6.285`, 
    2.095`}, {2.095`, 0.`, 2.095`}, {10.4721`, 0.`, 
    2.095`}, {6.285`, -2.0925`, 0.`}, {6.285`, 6.285`, 
    0.`}, {2.095`, -4.187`, -2.0925`}, {2.095`, 
    4.19`, -2.0925`}, {2.095`, 4.19`, 
    6.285`}, {10.4721`, 
    4.19`, -2.0925`}, {2.095`, 2.095`, 
    0.`}, {10.4721`, 2.095`, 
    0.`}, {0.`, -2.0925`, -2.0925`}, {8.377`, \
-2.0925`, -2.0925`}, {8.377`, \
-2.0925`, 6.285`}, {8.377`, 
    6.285`, -2.0925`}, {4.19`, -4.187`, 0.`}, {4.19`, 
    4.19`, 0.`}, {2.095`, -2.0925`, -4.187`}, {2.095`, \
-2.0925`, 4.19`}, {2.095`, 6.285`, 
    4.19`}, {10.4721`, -2.0925`, 
    4.19`}, {6.285`, -4.187`, 2.095`}, {6.285`, 4.19`, 
    2.095`}, {4.19`, 2.095`, -2.0925`}, {4.19`, 2.095`, 
    6.285`}, {0.`, 4.19`, 4.19`}, {8.377`, -4.187`, 4.19`}, {8.377`, 
    4.19`, -4.187`}, {8.377`, 4.19`, 4.19`}, {4.19`, 
    0.`, -4.187`}, {4.19`, 0.`, 4.19`}};

 Graphics3D[{Table[{Green, Sphere[surr[[i]], 0.4]}, {i, 1, Length[surr]}], Red, 
   Sphere[{5.238, 1.048, 1.047}, 0.5]}]]
```

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/bc357a1c-78a9-4eef-b5a1-ba5b233d545d

After changing `@ Length[surr]` to actual number 33 (but no more), It became rotatable like in desktop Mathematica version.

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/77bcaea1-ae9d-49d2-b318-ec0440415966

Is there any way to overcome this restriction? I don't think that this is a problem for WebGL to handle 10 or 1000 objects on the screen (client side load only?).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps `GraphicsGroup` might help?

Comment: @CarlLange, It works perfectly! Wow!

Comment: @CarlLange, thank you a lot :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I surmised in the comments, it appears that [`GraphicsGroup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGroup.html) is the way forward here.

```
CloudDeploy[Graphics3D[
  GraphicsGroup[{Table[{Green, Sphere[surr[[i]], 0.4]}, {i, 1, 
      Length[surr]}], Red, 
    Sphere[{5.238, 1.048, 1.047}, 0.5]}]]]
```

will result in rotatable 3D graphics.

I have tested this myself and it works fine with up to around 750 objects, after which my browser gave up and crashed.